# Solving system of equations, (2 equations 3 variables)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am a bit puzzled. Trying to solve this system of equations:

\begin{align*}
-x + 2y + z=0\\
x+2y+3z=0\\
\end{align*}

The solution should be \begin{align*}
x=-z\\
y=-z\\
\end{align*}

I just don't get the same solution. Please advice.

Comment: what solution did you obtain? to correct your mistake, I believe we need to know your working.

Comment: first, add the equations and see what you get. Then subtract the equations.

Comment: According to my lecture notes I have now:

\begin{align*}
-x + 2y + z=0\\
y+z=0\\
\end{align*}

But how to get to this point? I don't understand how it leads to this...

Answer (score 1):

adding both equations we get
$$y=-z$$ plugging this in the first equation we get $$-x-2z+z=0$$ tgherefore $$x=-z$$

Answer (score 0):

Start with the 2 equations

-x + 2y + z = 0

x + 2y + 3z = 0

Simplify

-x + 2y + z = x + 2y + 3z

Then solve for x

-x + z = x + 3z

-x = x + 2z

-2x = 2z

x = -z

Then solve for z

-x + z = x + 3z

-x = x + 2z

-2x = 2z

x = -z

z = -x

Then solve for y

-x + 2y + z = x + 2y + 3z

-x + 2y = x + 2y + 2z

2y = 2x + 2y + 2z

y = x + y + z

Now your equations are

x = -z

y = x + y + z

z = -x

Y can equal either x or z and the unchosen variable becomes negative

And since x - z has to equal 0, |x| must equal |z| And y = x or z so

|x| = |y| = |z|

So

|x| - |y| = 0

|x| - |z| = 0

|y| - |z| = 0

But y + z = 0

So y must equal x because x = -z and -z + z = 0

So in the end

x = -z = y

y = x = -z

z = -x = -y

Now put in a number and there you go.

If there is anything wrong with this please let me know.